# NET Core 6 Trouble updating a DB record using a DTO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dto, asp.net-core-6.0

This is my first time using DTO's to transfer data to the DB. I have this Create method that uses a DTO (I wont show that DTO because this is just an example) and works fine:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateDTO dto)
    {
        DropDowns();
        dto.Date_Added = DateTime.Now;
        try
        {
            _context.Add(dto.ToWC_Inbox());
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("It didn't work.");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        
        return View(dto.ToWC_Inbox());
    }
```

The create DTO lacks a few of the fields that need to be entered after the initial creation so I have a separate DTO for Editing that looks like this:

```
public class ReviewDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string First_Name { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Last_Name { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string? Marital_Status { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string? SSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(12)]
    public string? Phone_Number { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string Org_Number { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime Hire_Date { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Job_Title { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Work_Schedule { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime Injury_Date { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Injury_Time { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string DOT_12 { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Start_Time { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Injured_Body_Part { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string? Side { get; set; }
    public bool Missing_Work { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Missing_Work_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Begin_Missing_Date { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string? Begin_Missing_Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Return_To_Work_Date { get; set; }
    public bool Doctors_Release { get; set; }
    public bool? Treatment { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Treatment == true", ErrorMessage = "Treatment Date is required.")]
    public DateTime? Treatment_Date { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [RequiredIf("Treatment == true", ErrorMessage = "Treatment Provider is required.")]
    public string? Treatment_Provider { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [RequiredIf("Treatment == true", ErrorMessage = "Treatment Provider Phone is required.")]
    public string? Treatment_Provider_Phone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [RequiredIf("Treatment == true", ErrorMessage = "Where first treated is required.")]
    public string? Transport_First_Treatment { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [RequiredIf("Treatment == true", ErrorMessage = "The city of treatment is required.")]
    public string? Transport_City { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string Injury_Description { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string? Equipment { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Witness { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Supervisor_Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string? Supervisor_Phone { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string? Questioned { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string? Medical_History { get; set; }
    public bool Inbox_Submitted { get; set; }
    [RequiredIf("Inbox_Submitted == false", ErrorMessage = "The reason is required.")]
    public string? Inbox_Reason { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(250)]
    public string? Comments { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string User_Email { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string Supervisor_Email { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string Safety_Specialist_Email { get; set; } = null!;
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Optional_Email { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Optional_Email2 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string? Optional_Email3 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(254)]
    public string? HDHR_Manager_Email { get; set; }
    public int TX_EROI_Lag { get; set; }
    public string? Claim_Ruling { get; set; }
    public string? Injury_Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TTD_Onset_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Restricted_RTW_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Full_Duty_RTW_Date { get; set; }
    public bool Receiving_TTD { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date_TTD_Award_Notice { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Claim_Ruling_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Med_Excuse_To { get; set; }
    public string? Doctor { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RTW_Email_Encova { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_Start1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_End1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_Start2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_End2 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_Start3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Lost_Time_End3 { get; set; }
    public string? Status { get; set; }
    public string? HR_Comments { get; set; }
    public string Add_User { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime Date_Added { get; set; }
    public string? HR_User { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date_Modified { get; set; }

    public WC_Inbox ToCompletedWC_Inbox()
    {
        return new WC_Inbox
        {
            First_Name = this.First_Name,
            Last_Name = this.Last_Name,
            Gender = this.Gender,
            Marital_Status = this.Marital_Status,
            SSN = this.SSN,
            DOB = this.DOB,
            Address = this.Address,
            Phone_Number = this.Phone_Number,
            Org_Number = this.Org_Number,
            Hire_Date = this.Hire_Date,
            Job_Title = this.Job_Title,
            Work_Schedule = this.Work_Schedule,
            Injury_Date = this.Injury_Date,
            Injury_Time = this.Injury_Time,
            DOT_12 = this.DOT_12,
            Start_Time = this.Start_Time,
            Injured_Body_Part = this.Injured_Body_Part,
            Side = this.Side,
            Missing_Work = this.Missing_Work,
            Missing_Work_Date = this.Missing_Work_Date,
            Begin_Missing_Date = this.Begin_Missing_Date,
            Begin_Missing_Time = this.Begin_Missing_Time,
            Return_To_Work_Date = this.Return_To_Work_Date,
            Doctors_Release = this.Doctors_Release,
            Treatment = this.Treatment,
            Treatment_Date = this.Treatment_Date,
            Treatment_Provider = this.Treatment_Provider,
            Treatment_Provider_Phone = this.Treatment_Provider_Phone,
            Transport_First_Treatment = this.Transport_First_Treatment,
            Transport_City = this.Transport_City,
            Injury_Description = this.Injury_Description,
            Equipment = this.Equipment,
            Witness = this.Witness,
            Supervisor_Name = this.Supervisor_Name,
            Supervisor_Phone = this.Supervisor_Phone,
            Questioned = this.Questioned,
            Medical_History = this.Medical_History,
            Inbox_Submitted = this.Inbox_Submitted,
            Inbox_Reason = this.Inbox_Reason,
            Comments = this.Comments,
            User_Email = this.User_Email,
            Supervisor_Email = this.Supervisor_Email,
            Safety_Specialist_Email = this.Safety_Specialist_Email,
            Optional_Email = this.Optional_Email,
            Optional_Email2 = this.Optional_Email2,
            Optional_Email3 = this.Optional_Email3,
            HDHR_Manager_Email = this.HDHR_Manager_Email,
            TX_EROI_Lag = this.TX_EROI_Lag,
            Claim_Ruling = this.Claim_Ruling,
            Injury_Type = this.Injury_Type,
            TTD_Onset_Date = this.TTD_Onset_Date,
            Restricted_RTW_Date = this.Restricted_RTW_Date,
            Full_Duty_RTW_Date = this.Full_Duty_RTW_Date,
            Receiving_TTD = this.Receiving_TTD,
            Date_TTD_Award_Notice = this.Date_TTD_Award_Notice,
            Claim_Ruling_Date = this.Claim_Ruling_Date,
            Med_Excuse_To = this.Med_Excuse_To,
            Doctor = this.Doctor,
            RTW_Email_Encova = this.RTW_Email_Encova,
            Lost_Time_Start1 = this.Lost_Time_Start1,
            Lost_Time_End1 = this.Lost_Time_End1,
            Lost_Time_Start2 = this.Lost_Time_Start2,
            Lost_Time_End2 = this.Lost_Time_End2,  
            Lost_Time_Start3 = this.Lost_Time_Start3,
            Lost_Time_End3 = this.Lost_Time_End3,
            Add_User = this.Add_User,
            Date_Added = this.Date_Added,
            HR_User = this.HR_User,
            Date_Modified = this.Date_Modified,
        };
    }
}
```

And the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, ReviewDTO dto)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID: " + id);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DTO ID: " + dto.ID);
        DropDowns();
        if (id != dto.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Updating DB");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ID again: " + id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DTO ID again: " + dto.ID);
            _context.Update(dto.ToCompletedWC_Inbox());
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!WC_InboxExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
```

The problem is that instead of updating the existing record, the Edit method creates an entirely new record with the updated info and leaves the old record unedited.

Those print statesments are there to confirm that the dto.ID and the id that was gathered from the previous page match, and they do.

After doing some research I believe this is because I need to get the current version of the record out of the database, change it with the posted values, and save it back to the database, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this.

Could someone help me figure that part out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution, op?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should not `ToCompletedWC_Inbox` also map an `Id`. Something like:

```
public WC_Inbox ToCompletedWC_Inbox()
{
    return new WC_Inbox
    {
        ID = this.ID, // assuming WC_Inbox has ID property
        First_Name = this.First_Name,
        ....
```